# getting error while edit_order_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, netbeans-6.9

In my index.html.erb I have

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %>
```

Whenever I try to edit the order contents i got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Order#index 
undefined method `edit_order_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x13f4aeb>
```

How can I overcome it?

Comment: Is your route set up for the `orders#edit` path?

Comment: Show us a 'rake routes' command in bash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line of code in your routes.rb    `resources :orders`
or add following line of code in routes.rb

```
match 'orders/:id/edit' => 'orders#edit', :as => :edit_order
```

I assume, your controller name as `orders` and action `edit`.
use following code for form

```
<% form_for(@order, :url => {:action => :update}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: @user2150960 what is your controller and action name

Comment: when i edit the data and click on update then its giving error and controller name is order and action name is update

Comment: <h1>Editing order</h1>

<% form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pay_type %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>

Comment: NameError in OrdersController#update.   uninitialized constant OrdersController

Comment: add this in your routes.rb: resources :order

Comment: is it possible to change controller name as orders i.e. plueral